# Yii 2 codeception поключить модель

Tags: yii2

Хочу написать юнит тест. Но уперся в то что не могу подключить модель из приложения

yii2basic\tests\codeception\unit\models\BehaviorTest.php

```
<?php
namespace models;
use Yii;
use app\modules\video\models\Video;

class BehaviorTest extends \Codeception\TestCase\Test {

    /**
     * @var \UnitTester
     */
    protected $tester;

    protected function _before()
    {

    }

    protected function _after()
    {

    }

    // tests
    public function testMe()
    {
        $video = new Video();
        $video = $video::findAll();
        $this->assertEquals(0, count($video->id), 'Review count after save');
    }

}
```

> php I:\OpenServer\domains\yii2itmh\vendor\codeception\codeception\codecept
>   run unit Codeception PHP Testing Framework v2.1.7 Powered by PHPUnit
>   5.2.12 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> Unit Tests (1)
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Trying to test me (models\BehaviorTest::testMe)... Fatal error: Class
>   'app\modules\video\models\Video' not found in
>   I:\OpenServer\domains\yii2itmh\tests\codeception\unit\models\BehaviorTest.php
>   on line 26

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наследуйтесь от `yii\codeception\TestCase` или `yii\codeception\DbTestCase` вместо `\Codeception\TestCase\Test`.